# How to add values to Jquery UI Autocomplete text input

Tags: jquery-ui, jinja2

So I have a Jquery UI Autocomplete widget in my Jinja2 template which works great.  However, I want the value of each program to be the program ID, not the name.  IE:  `{{ p.id }}`  How do I set the name as the label and the id as the value?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var programs = [
        {% for p in programs %}
        '{{ p.Name }}',
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#programs" ).autocomplete({
        source: programs
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="program" id="programs" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this works!

The UI Autocomplete input is populated by the `label` attribute.  The `hidden_val` attribute sets the hidden input with the `select` event.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var programs = [
        {% for p in programs %}
        {
        hidden_val: "{{ p.id }}",
        label: "{{ p.Name }}"
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#programs" ).autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: programs,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $( "#program_val" ).val(ui.item.hidden_val);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="programs" />
<input type="hidden" id="programs_val" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://grover.open2space.com/content/using-jquery-autocomplete-ids that should do the trick!

Basically you supply the autocomplete textbox a list of `name|id` items. It will then show the name, and you only have to modify the textbox to put the id into a hidden form element using the `.result()` function. Like this:

```
$("#mytextbox")
  .autocomplete(data)
  .result(
    function (evt, data, formatted)
    {
      $("#hiddenIDbox").val(data[1]);
    }
);
```

Comment: I believe this article is geared at the now deprecated jQuery autocomplete plugin, not the jQueryUI one (which does not have a `result` function)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works, but as soon as the autocomplete suggestion is selected, the item id appears in the input field.. confusing for the users, I guess.  Any other ideas?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var programs = [
        {% for p in programs %}
        {
        value: "{{ p.id }}",
        label: "{{ p.Name }}"
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#programs" ).autocomplete({
        source: programs
    });
});
</script>
```